# Difference between Red Team, Penetration Testing and Blue Team

Tags: security, testing, penetration-testing

If a corporation includes as "internal entities" all of the following teams:
1) Red Team
2) Penetration Testing Team
3) Blue Team

What will be the differences between them? I find some difficulties in understanding the differences between Red and Pen Test!

And which team would have the wider scope and the higher authority?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate to be on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Red Team - act as the enemy.  The entire environment is within scope and their goal is to penetrate, maintain persistence, pivot, exfil, to examine what a determined enemy can do.  All tactics are available including social engineering.  Eventually the red team will get to a point where they own the entire network, or their actions will be caught and they will be stopped by the security administrators of the network they are attacking.  At that time they will report their findings to management in order to assist in the increasing the security of the network.  They keep copious notes as this information is valuable later on to fix the weaknesses they exploited.  Not many organizations do this, but they usually have an organic red team so the information gleaned from the red team is extremely sensitive.  Red team actions are controlled by the manager of the red team.

Penetration test - can use the same tactics of a red team (may be limited by management and the scope of the test), and is executed in controlled fashion usually dictated by management and/or asset owners.  Typically, the limiting scope of a pen test is time (execution time of the event) in which a report will be made to management.  Often in a pen test, before a flaw is exploited, management and system/network engineers must OK the attack to ensure it doesn't affect day to day operations.  The goal is the find weaknesses in systems/networks in order to increase the security posture.  Pen tester actions are controlled by business management and/or the asset owners.

Blue team - defend the network from the red team or pen tester.  The term "blue team" is also used for network/system auditor in which they are assisting the asset owners in securing and defending their own assets.

Answer (score 0):

Red Teams attack

Blue Teams defend

I don't know what they exactly they mean by Penetration Testing Team, but I would guess that they are a subset of the red team that focuses on penetration testing. There is more to attacking than penetration testing.

To answer your last question, the Red and Blue teams would probably be about equal, with the Penetration testing team being below the red team. Of course, without knowing anything else about the organization in question, there's no way to really know.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when a penetration Team is in mission, their only objectif is to find vulnerabilities in the system and they don't give a mind if they will be detected or not. 
Red team is a more complicated Job, in their mission they don't need to be discovered, they will play the role of attacker. Like "if they got detected they loose". Each step need to be well calculated.